# List index out of range in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I wrote a program like this:

```
reader=csv.reader(open("lrgdata.csv")) 
headers = reader.next()              
Amt_Wtotal=0             
Amt_Dtotal=0 
dataW =[] 
dataD=[] 
counts_W=defaultdict(int)
counts_D=defaultdict(int)
for row in reader:
   if(row[28]=='W'):
      counts_W[row[5]] += 1
      Amt_Wtotal += float(row[6])
      dataW.append(Amt_Wtotal)
   else:
   counts_D[row[5]] += 1
   Amt_Dtotal += float(row[6])
   dataD.append(Amt_Dtotal)
```

When I run this code with a file of 412KB I don't get an error but when I run with a 1.8MB file I get this error:

```
if(row[28]=='W'): IndexError: list index out of range
```

My file is something like this

#### Headers

```
personal_info_id_city,personal_info_sex,transaction_master_id_transaction_master,card_holder_info_id_terminal_info,transaction_master_id_terminal_info,account_info_id_account_info,transaction_master_amount,personal_info_dob_m,card_holder_info_card_issue_dt,personal_info_dob_h,transaction_master_transaction_from,personal_info_dob_d,transaction_master_transacted_on,account_info_balance_amt,personal_info_id_user_type,personal_info_dob_y,card_holder_info_card_issue_dt_y,transaction_master_transacted_on_y,transaction_master_transacted_on_d,card_holder_info_card_issue_dt_d,transaction_master_transacted_on_m,card_holder_info_card_issue_dt_h,transaction_master_transacted_on_h,card_holder_info_card_issue_dt_m,transaction_master_id_customer_info,personal_info_dob,card_holder_info_id_brch,card_holder_info_id_card_holder_info,transaction_master_transaction_type,_id,personal_info_id_customer_info
```

#### Values

```
2,M,17748,60,60,21768,1460.0,7,2011-04-02 00:00:00,0,B,5,2011-07-22 03:03:00,52.0,1,1992,2011,2011,22,2,7,0,3,4,21768,1992-07-05 00:00:00,26,21768,W,50f38a469cf9c253d600000c,21768

1,M,18002,3,3,1746,3480.0,2,2011-04-07 00:00:00,0,B,5,2011-07-25 01:03:00,123.0,1,1985,2011,2011,25,7,7,0,1,4,1746,1985-02-05 00:00:00,3,1746,D,50f38a469cf9c253d600000d,1746
```

Could you please tell how to find correlation between two datsets which is an a list?

Comment: It looks like the 1.8MB file has a line in it that has fewer fields than expected. It's not the size of the file, it's one or more of the lines in it.

Comment: how to wite an exception for the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        if(row[28]=='W'):
            counts_W[row[5]] += 1
            Amt_Wtotal += float(row[6])
            dataW.append(Amt_Wtotal)
        else:
            counts_D[row[5]] += 1
            Amt_Dtotal += float(row[6])
            dataD.append(Amt_Dtotal)
     except:
         #handle the exception here. 
         # "continue" will ignore it and move to the next item in the loop.
         # I suspect what you actually want is to duplicate the "else" clause here.
```

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: o/p
Deposit Details for the given data set defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2239': 1, '1700': 1, '2458': 1, '10016': 1, '2056': 1, '2376': 1, '1965': 1, '1974': 1, '2425': 1, '21768': 1, '2069': 1, '2404': 1, '2402': 1, '1763': 1, '1762': 1, '1910': 1, '1746': 1, '10036': 1}) [3480.0, 7080.0, 10440.0, 13200.0, 16800.0, 20400.0, 23880.0, 27480.0, 30840.0, 38040.0, 41520.0, 44880.0, 48480.0, 52080.0, 55680.0, 59280.0, 62520.0, 66120.0, 67580.0, 69620.0, 69621.0] count== 21
, i.e i have took amount in a seperate list , can i append tat also to a dictionary and how can i access it.

Comment: You mean this answered your question, or there's still some issue?

Comment: sir reply for the above question]